# Unicode to callable in python

Tags: python

I have methods written in Python like `one()`, `two()`, `three(x)`.

And in my JSON config file I have  `x=one`, `y=two` and `z=three`

Then the Python code looks like:

```
        temp=json.load(above json file)
        a=temp["x"]
        a()
```

The above code gives an error:

> Error:Unicode cannot callable.

Please look into it and help me to get this resolved.

Comment: Your json config file doesn't look like a json file. And format your code to display here.

Comment: {"x":"ONE","Y":"TWO","Z":"THREE"} this is in actual json. This is valid json, that i have confirmed with jsonlint.com

Comment: Assuming you the JSON matches the method exactly you could use `globals()[string_version_of_function_name]` or build a local dictionary of functions.

Comment: @Trengot note that that's obviously dangerous if the data comes from an untrusted source.

Comment: @райтфолд absolutely. I'd go with the local dictionary or at least sanitise the names first.

Comment: i iam looking solution , without using local dict

Comment: @SakthivelThandabani, why? What's wrong with a dictionary?

Comment: i am creating frame work for an application.. this will able to communicate various open source applications, however my frame work should be same for all applications, JSON will handle mapping

Answer (score 2):

What you get from your json file is a python dict with unicode strings as values. The fact that these unicode strings match your functions names doesn't make the unicode strings "alias" to your functions - you have to handle this mapping by yourself. What you want is something like:

```
def one():
    print "in one"

def two():
    print "in two"

def three():
    print "in three"

functions = {
    "one": one,
    "two": two,
    "three": three,
}

# directly write it as a python dict
temp = {
    "x": "one",
    "y": "two",
    "z": "three",
}

funcname = temp["x"]
func = functions[funcname]
func()
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno. But i should not map the functions locally(in python file). my python is application script which should able to communicate various open source code without any modification as the mapping will always be in  JSON.:-)

Comment: You should probably mention that there is a way to turn strings into names via `locals()`.

Comment: i am new to python, can you please breif

Comment: tl;dr: Instead of `a()`, do `locals()[a]()`.